# Who triggered my trigger?

Tags: database, triggers, db2, sql-execution-plan

My situation:
I want to make a historical table of the use of a truly sensitive table I have in db2. 
That table is being accessed by a generic user through some static plans (already compiled).

What I want:
I need to record the time and WHO did an update on it.

I am planing to use triggers, since it seems that fits my needs, but I still don't know how to get within the trigger who "triggered the trigger". 

I mean, to know the batch or executable who called the static plan.

Note: since each executable is using a different plan, it would be acceptable to get some kind of plan id.

Is it feasible? How can I do it?

Comment: Which DB2 platform and version are you asking about?

Comment: I am using DB2 Z/OS V9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else needs it, I was able to find the way:

```
GETVARIABLE(SYSIBM.SYSPLAN);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special DB2 register called `USER` which stores the information of authorization id. You can use it the same way use TIMESTAMP in your insert or update query of Trigger.

```
SET HIST_LAST_UPDATE_USER = USER;
```

If you are okay with schema then you can also use CURRENT SCHEMA or CURRENT SQLID.